# c++ regex: matching a label followed by comma separated values

Tags: c++, regex

From the string

```
label: first, second, third
```

I want to extract:

- label
- first
- second
- third

All of the following inputs are valid:

```
label: first, second, third
label: first
label
```

(**Edit**: the list can have 0, 1 or n items)

i've come up with two different patterns, none of them gives me the "right" result:

```
(?:(\w+ (\d+))| -> (\w+)|, (\w+))+
```

gives me

- label: first, second, third
- , third
- label
- first
- third

  re (\w+)(?:: (\w+))?(?:, (\w+))*

gives me

- label: first, second, third
- label
- first
- third

Here is [a test implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45a39fd37ebd34fa)

How can i get it to output?

- label: first, second, third
- label
- first
- **second**
- third

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(\w+)(?::\s*(\w+)(?:,\s*(\w+)(?:,\s*(\w+))?)?)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/29g21P/1)

Comment: thanks! at first it looked fine... but it does not work on: `label: first, second, third, fourth` (it was not specified that it could have four items... but yes, the list can have zero, one or n items). i'll add this to the question.

Comment: *"A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data"*.

Comment: this means that what i want to do is impossible?

Comment: You might use `regex_search` to iterate over a capture afterward, but you cannot capture multiple groups with one repeated group.